# lighttpd not reliable

Tags: lighttpd, fastcgi, django

I have a lighttpd running which serves a django-based webservice. It was running well for some months, but from today on, it returns a 410 sometimes, and sometimes fails silently.
To test, I make a curl-call, which most time runs fine; it returns some json test-data. Some times. however, it does not return any data, but the call seems to have run well, since I don't get an error code.

When I post to my webservice via third-party-packaged like boto, I sometimes get a "410 gone" - but I do not find any entry in the lighttpd error log.

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to avoid this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its lighttpd and not your Python cgi/daemon? I've seen problems like this before with running php as a cgi and it running our of resources.

Comment: no, I'm not sure about this. The fcgi-processes look like this:  python ./manage.py runfcgi socket=/var/www/myproject/myproject.sock pidfile=/var/www/myproject/myproject.pid maxchildren=30